# How to highlight time series in some date ranges in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, highlight, dygraphs

I need to highlight some dates ranges in my time series chart, but I can´t go ahead.

The dataset used is following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(xts)
library(zoo)


df <- read.csv("https://github.com/rhozon/datasets/raw/master/dataset_1a.csv", header = TRUE, sep =",") %>%
 mutate(
   dates = as.Date(dates)
 ) %>% 
  filter(
    dates >= "2019-01-01"
  ) %>%
  glimpse()

df_xts <- xts(df[,-1, drop = FALSE], order.by = df[,1]) %>% as.xts()

class(df_xts)

head(df_xts)
```

Then I tryed the following `PerfomanceAnalytics` commands:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

# Create period to hold the 3 months of 2020
period <- c("2020-01/2020-03")

# Highlight the first three months of 2020
chart.TimeSeries(df$prices_usa, period.areas = period,  period.color = "lightgrey")
```

with no success...

```
Error in try.xts(x, error = "'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible") : 
  'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible
```

By using the `dygraphs` package...

```
library(dygraphs)

dygraph( df$prices_usa ) %>%

  dyShading(from = "2020-06-30", to = "2020-09-01") %>%
  dyAnnotation("2020-08-01", text = "X", tooltip = "date range") %>%
  dyAxis("x", drawGrid = TRUE) %>% 
  dyEvent("2020-06-30", "Jul 2020", labelLoc = "bottom") %>% 
  dyEvent("2020-09-01", "Sep 2020", labelLoc = "bottom") %>% 
  dyOptions(drawPoints = FALSE, pointSize = 2) #%>%
```

And again I found another issue:

```
Error in dygraph(df$prices_usa) : Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'.
```

I didn´t tryed with the ggplot2 package because I need to use it with interaticvity.

Could someone recommend me a solution to these issues or something that is simpler to do (even with ggplot2+plotly) that can be useful for me to demarcate or highlight some ranges of dates/periods in my time series graphs?

Answer (score 0):

Using the reproducible xts object in the Note at the end use plot and xblocks.  To specify a different color use something like `adjustcolor("blue", 0.2)` in place of `grey(...)`. For many other approaches google *R shading recessions*

```
library(xts)

plot(as.zoo(aapl))
xblocks(aapl, ifelse(time(aapl) %in% time(aapl[period]), grey(.2, .2), NA))
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
period <- "2020-01/2020-03"
aapl <- Cl(AAPL)
```

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck ! But, I tryed to use this `period <- "2020-01/2020-03"

plot(as.zoo(df_xts))

xblocks(df_xts, ifelse(time(df_xts) %in% time(df_xts[period]), grey(.2, .2), NA))` but it didn´t worked for highlighting date ranges.

Comment: The question was about plotting *one* column against time in a *single* panel but you are attempting to plot *two* in a *multi-panel* plot thereby introducing the problem.   Either (1) choose which column you want to plot, e.g. `df_xts[, 1]` or else (2) tell it to plot both in the same panel by adding `screen = 1` as an argument to the plot command.

Comment: What about: `period <- "2020-01/2020-03"  plot(as.zoo(df_xts$prices_usa))  xblocks(df_xts$prices_usa, ifelse(time(df_xts) %in% time(df_xts[period]), grey(.2, .2), NA)) `

Comment: I used this command by using ggplot2 package: `library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ggplotly(
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data = df, 
            aes(xmin = as.numeric(as.Date(c("2019-02-01"))),
                xmax = as.numeric(as.Date(c("2019-02-05"))), 
                ymin = 300,
                ymax = 800), 
            alpha = 0.15) + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(dates, prices_usa)) + 
  ggtitle('timeseries with weekends highlighted')
)` but the dates in the graphs seens to be wrong...someone knows how to fix it ?